# What are branches in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I have several Git repositories that all have one branch called 'master.' But what are branches and what can you do with them?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should try reading documentation some time, or perhaps using Google.

Comment: @siride: Perhaps you should try being less condescending and linking to what you consider to be the best description of what questioners are asking for.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is a certain base level of research people need to be willing to carry out.  Almost every Git tutorial or piece of documentation talks about branches and pretty early on.  If Time Machine spent any time at all reading about how Git works, he/she'd have already gotten the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branches are used when you want to develop a specific feature in an environment for itself. It's so you don't mix untested code with trunk, the generally stable version. You branch until you have developed and tested the feature, then you merge the branch back into trunk.

Comment: This answer is based more on SVN, but it works the same with Git.

Comment: So, for example: I have an app called Foo which is at master. I am developing a feature called Bar, so I do this in a separate branch and then merge when Bar is completed and tested?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how you could do it.

Comment: and Git has good integration with SVN , some people do the merge in Git then put it back to SVN without the notice of the company :D

Answer (score 2):

Branches are usually parallel streams of development independent from each other. Similar to a timeline. [Here](http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1135/5153884916_23acf12aee.jpg) is a picture of a software project with multiple branches.

You might have a branch that contains all your stable work for example and another which contains experimental work. You might have another staging branch in between which is used to qualify changes from the experimental branch before moving it into the stable one. These are all [branching strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975/branching-strategies). Different teams might have different branches etc.

Depending on your version control system, the implementation and uses of branches might be vastly different. In centralised version control systems (e.g. SVN), a [branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04.html) is essentially a copy of then entire source code at the time of branching (similar to a `cp -R` on a filesystem). After that, development will proceed on this branch independent on the main one. So you will have something like this

```
--o---0---o---o---o---- (parent branch)
       \
        \---o---o---0--- (new branch)
```

The `o` signifies a commit and the `0` is the point of branching. The branches you make with this system are global (everyone on your project can see them) and they're quite heavy. It is possible to `merge` the new branch back into the parent branch when you want. This might entail [`merge conflicts`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s03.html).

With decentralised VCs (I'm using git as an example), [branches](http://book.git-scm.com/3_basic_branching_and_merging.html) are much more lightweight. They're simply pointers to a position in the DAG that represents the history of your project. You can push them forward by creating a new commit. Also, the branches will be local (i.e. only you can see them unless you decide to publish them).

However, branching and merging has some conceptual content that you can't figure out without reading the docs. I'd suggest that you look at the documentation of the VCS you're using and come back on stack overflow with specific questions if you have any.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice article that I like to refer to all the time: [Successful Git Branching Model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

The article is a practical and successful case study of a team who collaborate effectively with Git.

Answer (score 1):

As you are new to GIT, I enthusiastically recommend read Chapter 3 in this book:

http://progit.org/book/

@Noufal and @Jakob already gave a good answer I believe. However, when it comes to the practical side of using GIT, you will always make mistakes, because of the different syntax of branches (master, origin master, origin/master, etc.

Also, I recommend reading the concepts of GIT rather than how to use it, so check this link and you might be interested in reading about branching:

http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cduan/technical/git/

Answer (score 0):

complementing the provided answers, there is a git webcast regarding branching and merging over `http://gitcasts.com/` or go directly to `http://blip.tv/file/4094707`