# Syncing branches in svn

Tags: .net, svn, version-control

I am working on two branches concurrently. If a change is made to the trunk then I sync the two branches with the trunk.

What strategies do developers use syncing branches e.g. If I commit five changes to branch 1 and two changes to branch 2 during the week then should I sync branch 1 with 2 and branch 2 with branch 1. Historically I would wait until the branch is complete and then sync it with the trunk ie I would not usuAlly sync branches. Should I be syncing branches?

Answer (score 0):

Svn doesn't really understand relationships between branches. when you make a branch svn just makes a copy and then forgets about it.

More modern version control systems like git and tfs (and many others) actually understand that when you make a branch,  the two places in versioncontrol are connected. that way, when you merge, the version control system understand what changes to take from each branch.

There are a variety of branching strategies you can employ. check out this page (its old, but still relevant)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668955.aspx

Here are some newer pages on the subject
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782536.aspx
http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/

And a great SO thread
[Branching Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975/branching-strategies)

You can still use svn though, but merging will just be a lot more work. for that reason you'll probably want to minimize the amount of merges you have to do (but if you have to do it, you have to:))